# Copy range values one by one

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets, in which L6 of Sheet 1 will have a data from a range in sheet 2 B:B. I need a macro, upon a command it shall select B:B, then copy first cell value (B1) to L6 of sheet1, upon next click it shall select B2 and copy the value to L6, upon reaching the last value or a blank cell it shall display a message "no value".

Comment: Here are some loop examples http://www.xlorate.com/excel-vba-loops.html

Comment: Hi Neelesh, have you tried anythng? If yes please put the code so that we can help improving it :)

Comment: Thanks for the link Dave but it didn't help me what I'm looking for.@Linga I'm using a data validation list as of now.But selecting each time from the list quite tedious.I've almost 1500 entries in column B

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MyMacro()
    Static curr As Range
    If curr Is Nothing Then Set curr = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")

    If curr.Value = vbNullString Then
       MsgBox "No Value"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    ' although Select is unrecommneded in VBA, but since it is required in the problem statement...
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    curr.Select
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L6").Value = curr.Value
    Set curr = curr.Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```