# Display month as a letter

Tags: excel, vba

Is there VBA code for displaying current month as alphabets.
Like Jan-A,Feb-B...Dec-L. I know it is possible to get it as text but I'm looking for alphabets.

Answer (score 2):

This gives you the current month as "A" for January, "B" for February, etc..

VBA:

```
Chr(Month(Now) + 64)
```

Edit (for completeness, thanks @Jeeped):
Formula:

```
=CHAR(MONTH(NOW()) + 64)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply,I want to include it in cell W6.How to modify it?

Comment: in VBA, you can write `Range("W6") = Chr(Month(Now) + 64)`. If you want to use it as a formula, then make it a UDF (User-Defined Function)

Comment: Thanks a Lot A.S.H ,it worked.Could you please solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562135/copy-range-values-one-by-one question of mine?

Comment: @Neelesh please see the answer to that question. But in general, kindly, please avoid this kind of requests, because each question should be solved on its own, especially when the issues are totally unrelated.

Comment: `=CHAR(MONTH(TODAY()) + 64)`

Comment: Noted ASH.Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Neelesh so should I delete these answers (this and the other one) or do you accept them as solution?