# Excel Macro Insert Data From another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Could someone help me to do the following:
I need to copy (or using a similar VBA function) a range of cells to another worksheet.

However, the range will probably include empty cells that I don't want to include with the data, and I also need to **insert** the values (rather than Paste) so they don't override stuff already on the destination sheet.
`.Value` rather than `.Paste` or `.PasteSpecial` is preferred.

Hope this makes sense

---

### EDIT

Here is some code I have tried, but this still overrides (even if the selected cells were empty) the data in the destination sheet.

```
Sub MakeQuote()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Sheets("Code Input Sheet").Range("A9:C800").Copy
  Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\j\Documents\Trial.xltm").Activate
  Sheets("Special Quote").Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, skipBlanks:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
Err_Execute:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "Copying Successful :)" Else _
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So basically it needs to find just the data and copy/insert it into the destination sheet.

Being used to HTML and PHP this is a bit of a jump in the dark for me :)

Many thanks everyone

Comment: If you haven't written any code yet, do a search on this site, there are plenty of examples of this nature to get you started. Once you have some code, edit this post to include your code and someone will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample of what kind of code you are looking for is below.

However I would recommend doing a few more Google searches on VBA programming before posting similar questions. This will let you improve upon code listed below. For example, `Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row` uses a build in function/method to figure out what is the last row you wish to copy; which may or may not be what you are looking for.

Further this question highly resembles other questions on Stack Overflow for example: 
[Copy range values one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562135/copy-range-values-one-by-one)

Nevertheless if you wish to use the code below just change the source worksheet from "Sheet1" to whichever sheet your source data is from, and the source range from "C1" to whichever range on that sheet you are using. Similarly you'll need to do with the target.

```
Sub rangeCopy()
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sourceCounter As Long
    Dim targetCounter As Long
    Dim outString As String

    'Change the source and target sheet as needed.
    Set sourceRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1")
    Set targetRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    lastRow = sourceRange.Parent.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For sourceCounter = 0 To lastRow - 1

        'Copy the cell you want to transfer from the source apge
        outString = Trim(sourceRange.Offset(sourceCounter).Value)

        'Find the next empty cell in the target worksheet
        While (Trim(targetRange.Offset(targetCounter).Value) <> "")
            targetCounter = targetCounter + 1
        Wend

        targetRange.Offset(targetCounter).Value = outString
    Next

End Sub
```

**Updated Code**

This code was updated to match an input source range that contains multiple cells.

```
sub rangeCopy()
    Dim sourceRange As Range, loopRange As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sourceCounter As Long
    Dim targetCounter As Long
    Dim outString As String
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim startCol As Long
    Dim endCol As Long
    Dim colCounter As Long

    'Change the source and target sheet as needed.
    Set sourceRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C34")
    Set targetRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    startRow = sourceRange.Row
    lastRow = sourceRange.Rows.Count
    startCol = sourceRange.Column
    endCol = sourceRange.Columns.Count - 1
    Set loopRange = sourceRange.Parent.Cells(startRow, startCol)


    For colCounter = 0 To endCol
        targetCounter = 0
        For sourceCounter = 0 To lastRow - 1

            'Copy the cell you want to transfer from the source apge
            outString = Trim(loopRange.Offset(sourceCounter, colCounter).Value)

            'Find the next empty cell in the target worksheet
            While (Trim(targetRange.Offset(targetCounter, colCounter).Value) <> "")
                targetCounter = targetCounter + 1
            Wend

            targetRange.Offset(targetCounter, colCounter).Value = outString
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - but I get a Type Mismatch on the `outString = Trim` line... Could you help?

Comment: I was able to reproduce it. What you are doing is your entering a range as a multi cell range for the source. Which is why you can't save that value as a string.

Comment: I updated my answer to be flexible and handle a multi-cell source range. The code does exactly what I think you want it to do mainly coping cells into the first occurrence of a blank cell.

Comment: Just for clarification (that comment before looks too ambiguous, sorry) - the target sheet already has content below where the 'pasted' data is going, and this needs to move down if the data needs more rows. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Value to Value From Range

Example

```
Option Explicit
'// Value to Value
Sub Value_To_Value()

    Dim FilePath As String

    '// Workbook1 File Path
    FilePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Temp\" '<- Change Path

    With Range("A1:A10")
        .Value = "='" & FilePath & "[Workbook1.xlsm]Sheet1'!B1:B10"
    End With

End Sub
```

MSDN [Environ Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fx287h4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)